# I need to create a button in html

Tags: python, django

Good time of day. I have a Field and a button that changes a record in the Database when clicked. I want to not have this field, and when I press the button, I go to the already filled field, and I can customize it, and then save it by pressing the button.

Here is my code, I hope it will help in some way. I would also be grateful for help in improving the code, I'm a beginner.

today.html

```html
<title>Todoist</title>
<h1>Сегодня</h1>
<h2>Задачи</h2>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'todoist:add' %}" >{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name='tasks' pattern=".{2,}" required title='Минимум два символа!!!'>
  <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Добавить задачу</button>
</form>


{% for todo in todos%}
<div>
  <p>  {{todo.tasks}}</p>
  <a href={% url 'todoist:delete' today_id=todo.id%}>Удалить</a>
  <form action="{% url 'todoist:update' today_id=todo.id%}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name='tasks'>
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Изменить</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import Today
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods


def index(request):
    todos = Today.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'today.html', {'todos':todos})

@require_http_methods(['POST'])
 def add(request):
     tasks = request.POST["tasks"]
     task = Today(tasks=tasks)
     task.save()
     return redirect('todoist:index')
                    
def delete(request, today_id):
    todo = Today.objects.get(id=today_id)
    todo.delete()
    return redirect('todoist:index')

def update(request, today_id):
    todo = Today.objects.get(id=today_id)
    todo.tasks = request.POST.get('tasks')
    todo.save()
    return redirect('todoist:index')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new view to handle the editing functionality.

```
def edit(request, today_id):
todo = Today.objects.get(id=today_id)
todo.edit_mode = True
todo.save()
return redirect('todoist:index')
```

Don't forget to update your URL configuration and button.

For button;

```
{% for todo in todos %}
<div>
  {% if todo.edit_mode %}
    <form action="{% url 'todoist:update' today_id=todo.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="tasks" value="{{ todo.tasks }}">
      <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'todoist:index' %}">Отмена</a>
  {% else %}
    <p>{{ todo.tasks }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'todoist:delete' today_id=todo.id %}">Удалить</a>
    <a href="{% url 'todoist:edit' today_id=todo.id %}">Изменить</a>
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

For Url;

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'todoist'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add/', views.add, name='add'),
    path('delete/<int:today_id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('update/<int:today_id>/', views.update, name='update'),
    path('edit/<int:today_id>/', views.edit, name='edit'),
]
```

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly should I change the button and URL?At the moment I press the button, but nothing happens (I left the function name as it was before)

Comment: With these changes, you've implemented a toggle between view and edit modes for each task. Clicking the "Изменить" (Edit) link will take you to the edit mode where you can modify the task in an input field and then save the changes. Clicking "Отмена" (Cancel) will revert to the view mode without making any changes. I edited my answer

Comment: I did everything as you wrote, but for some reason nothing happens when you click on the Edit button

Comment: It seems that everything is written correctly, but for some reason everything does not work exactly

Comment: clean your cache and put url to href.

Comment: How i can clean cache? The URLs are placed exactly as you wrote